# PHPSpec, testing code that uses fluent mock

Tags: php, doctrine, fluent-interface, bdd

I've just completed writing a spec for a Doctrine2 repository. The repo contains only one method so far, the spec for which takes in an OAuth Identity token object (that contains an ID that matches up with a database table in my system) and returns either NULL or a UserAccount entity.

Due to the fluent nature of Doctrine query building, my test seems quite verbose, and I have used a lot of lines in my test wiring the 'fluent' aspect of the Query api together.

Repository:

```
namespace Users\Repository;

use Users\Entity\UserAccount;
use ZF\MvcAuth\Identity;

class UserAccountRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getFromIdentity(Identity\IdentityInterface $identity)
    {
        if ($identity instanceof Identity\GuestIdentity) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$identity instanceof Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity) {
            return null;
        }

        /** @var $identity Identity\AuthenticatedIdentity */
        $id = $identity->getRoleId();

        if (!is_int($id)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->createNamedQuery('u')
            ->where('u.id = :id')
            ->setParameter(':id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Spec:

```
/**
 * @mixin \Users\Repository\UserAccountRepository
 */
class UserAccountRepositorySpec extends ObjectBehavior
{
    function let(
        ORM\EntityManager $em,
        ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $classMetadata
    )
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($em, $classMetadata);
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('Users\Repository\UserAccountRepository');
    }

    function it_get_a_user_account_from_an_identity(
        ORM\EntityManager $em,
        Identity $identity,
        TestQuery $query
    )
    {
        $identity->getRoleId()->willReturn(4);

        $em->createQuery(Argument::any())->willReturn($query);
        $query->where('u.id = :id')->willReturn($query);
        $query->setParameter(':id', 4)->willReturn($query);
        $query->getQuery(Argument::any())->willReturn($query);
        $query->getResult(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->getFromIdentity($identity);
    }

    function it_should_always_return_null_when_passed_a_guest_identity(
        GuestIdentity $identity
    )
    {
        $this->getFromIdentity($identity)->shouldBeNull();
    }
}

/** concrete mock due to ORM\Query being final */
class TestQuery extends ORM\AbstractQuery
{
    public function getSql(){}
    public function _doExecute(){}
    public function where(){}
    public function getQuery(){}
}
```